# How to pass a variable to a Kivy label?

Tags: android, ios, python-3.x, kivy, mqtt

I have been trying to pass the message received in the `on_ message` function to the `testlab` label for a couple of days, with no results. Could you give me an example?
Any other corrections or advice are very welcome.
This is my code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient



KV = """

Screen:
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "ON"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.3}
        on_press: app.test_button("on")
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "OFF"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.7}
        on_press: app.test_button("off")
    MDLabel:
        id: testlab
        text: ""
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        
"""

    
class MqttApp():

    def __init__(self,broker_address,port,user,password):   

        self.password = password
        self.user = user
        self.port = port
        self.broker_address = broker_address
        
    
    broker_address= "***********"  
    port = 1883                   
    user = "****************"                  
    password = "***************"    

    client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               
    client.username_pw_set(user, password=password) 
    client.connect(broker_address,port)
    client.subscribe("raspytemp")
    client.loop_start() 
    
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        pass

    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print (msg.payload)
        #how I can pass msg to testlab? 
        #Screen.ids["testlab"].text = (msg.payload)<-----------????

    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message



class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):  
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light" 
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)        

    def test_button(self,state):
        MqttApp.client.publish("kivytest", state)
        


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Does your app use a `ScreenManager`? If so, your `Screen` instance should have a `name` attribute, which is how you would access that `Screen`.

Comment: I haven’t used ScreenManager,  but I suppose I have to.

Comment: I tried to implement the ScreenManager but without success.

Answer (score 0):

It just seems odd to use a `Screen` without a `ScreenManager`. But as your code stands, I think you might be able to replace the commented:

```
#Screen.ids["testlab"].text = (msg.payload)<-----------????
```

with:

```
self.root.ids["testlab"].text = msg.payload
```

assuming `msg.payload` is a string.

Comment: This instruction works only within the  MainApp class.  If I try to use it inside the MqttApp class it gives me an error.

Comment: I haven't implemented the ScreenManager yet because I'm only doing testing for now but I'll have to implement it

Comment: 'If I try to use it inside the MqttApp class it gives me an error.' - that's most probably because the class `MqttApp` is not inherited from `EventDispatcher`. However, just a guess, does it work if you replace `self` (as John Anderson suggested) by `MDApp.get_running_app()`.

Comment: I said to replace the code you have commented out. I saw that the name was `MqttApp` and mistakenly assumed is was the `App` class. So my answer will not work as written. The suggestion by @ApuCoder should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Still don't understand how to pass `msg` from `on_message` to `testlbl`in `MainWindow`.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient

KV = """

ScreenManager:
    MainWindow:
        name: 'Mainwindow'
    SecondWindow:
        name: 'Secondwindow'
    ThirdWindow:
        name: 'Thirdwindow'
 
<MainWindow>:
    name: "Mainwindow"
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "ON"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.1, "center_y": 0.3}
        on_press: app.test_button("on")
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "OFF"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.1, "center_y": 0.7}
        on_press: app.test_button("off")
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "MENU"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.3, "center_y": 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Secondwindow'  
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "IMPOSTAZIONI"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Thirdwindow'
    MDLabel:
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: 30
        bold: True
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'center'
        valign:'middle'
        text: "HOME"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.9}      
    MDLabel:
        id: testlab
        text: "incoming"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.5}

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "Secondwindow"
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "HOME"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.3, "center_y": 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Mainwindow'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "IMPOSTAZIONI"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Thirdwindow'
    MDLabel:
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: 30
        bold: True
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'center'
        valign:'middle'
        text: "MENU"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.9}

<ThirdWindow>:
    name: "Thirdwindow"
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "HOME"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.3, "center_y": 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Mainwindow'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "MENU"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Secondwindow'    
    MDLabel:
        text_size: self.size
        font_size: 30
        bold: True
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'center'
        valign:'middle'
        text: "IMPOSTAZIONI"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.9}
    
"""

class MainWindow(Screen):

    def print_data(self,msg):
        self.ids["testlbl"].text = msg   #<-------------------
    
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ThirdWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
    
class MqttApp():

    def __init__(self,broker_address,port,user,password):   
        self.password = password
        self.user = user
        self.port = port
        self.broker_address = broker_address
       
    broker_address= "*******"  
    port = 1883                   
    user = "******"                  
    password = "******"    

    client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               
    client.username_pw_set(user, password=password) 
    client.connect(broker_address,port)
    client.subscribe("raspytemp/#")
    client.loop_start() 
    
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        pass

    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print (msg.payload)
        MainWindow.print_data(msg) #<--------------------------

    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message

sm = ScreenManager()
screens = [MainWindow(name="Mainwindow"), SecondWindow(name="Secondwindow"), ThirdWindow(name="Thirdwindow")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "Secondwindow"

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):  
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light" 
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)    

    def test_button(self,stato):
        MqttApp.client.publish("kivytest", stato)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    MainApp().run()
```